# How to get total row number excel in java include row null?

Tags: java, apache-poi

i'm have file .xls, into i ignore three Row and begin at row is three.

Example: total number its is 20, i'm ignore three line, and begin modify with line 4, but I get row num (`sheet.getLastRowNum()` then is: 17, why not is 20? How to I can get all of line number?, in this case is 20.

Comment: Show us your .xls file and your code.

Answer (score 0):

try using `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()`. this should give you the 20 rows in your case

Comment: Hm, actually this one should return 17, and `sheet.getLastRowNum()` should give 19 (because null-based)

Comment: for me it works fine. i am using this`CellReference c2 = new CellReference(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1, data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1);` to get the very last cell with content in an excel sheet and it works flawless

Comment: I was confused : sheet.getLastRowNum() and sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(), when found in error, I've resolved.thank everyone !